Visual Studio 2022 community Issue
I've recently switched to a Mac (Mac 15 M3), and I've discovered that Visual Studio is no longer supported for Mac users. To work around this, I installed a Windows virtual machine on Parallels and attempted to install the latest version of Visual Studio 2022 Community Edition.
However, I'm encountering an issue: the Azure Development workload is not appearing in the list of available workloads during installation. This problem doesn't occur on a standard Windows machine but does persist on the virtual machine. I've tried several solutions without success. Could you assist me with this?

Ensured Windows is up to date
Checked virtual machine configuration
Installed required components manually
Repaired Visual Studio installation
Used an alternative installation method
Checked Visual Studio extensions

